# Animation with Sprites HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm trying very hard to make a game, but I'm stuck trying to make an animation.

I'm trying to adapt a tutorial I found, but I'm not seeing an animation. Instead, I see the whole `.png` file drawn on the screen.

Here is my code (as well as a link to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ae3nj03a/3/)

I'd appreciate any help or guidance.

```
var fantom = new Image(300,60); //obrazek ma wymiary 24,24
fantom.src = 'obrazki/SpriteGracz.png';

function draw() {
var nr_klatki = 1;
var liczba_klatek_fantom = 5;
var szerokosc_klatki = fantom.width / liczba_klatek_fantom;
var wysokosc_klatki = fantom.height;0
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    ggctx=c.getContext('2d');
c.fillStyle = "#111";
   //c.fillRect(0,0,200,100);

nr_klatki++;
if (nr_klatki>liczba_klatek_fantom) {
    nr_klatki = 1;
}
var xklatki = (nr_klatki-1)*szerokosc_klatki;
ggctx.drawImage(fantom, xklatki, 0, szerokosc_klatki, wysokosc_klatki, 60, 35, szerokosc_klatki, wysokosc_klatki);  
return draw;    
}

function rysuj(callback){
    var gracz = document.createElement("canvas");
    gctx = gracz.getContext("2d");
    gctx.fillStyle = "black";
    //gracz.width = 640;
    //gracz.height = 480;
    gracz = new Image();
    gracz.onload = function(){
            setInterval(draw(), 20);

    };

    gracz.src = "../obrazki/SpriteGracz.png";
    //gctx.arc(310, 410, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    //gctx.fill();
  //  dom.dodKlase(gracz, "plansza");
    dom.dodKlase(gracz, "gracze");
    return gracz;
    callback();
}

 //function ()

function setup(){
    var boardElement = $("#ekran-gry .ekran-planszy")[0];
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    dom.dodKlase(canvas, "plansza");
    boardElement.appendChild(createBackground());
    boardElement.appendChild(rysuj());
    boardElement.appendChild(canvas);

   // rysuj();        
}
```

Comment: While we all sympathize with your position (all professional developers have been in your shoes), "spot the bug" questions are off-topic on this site. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/211627

Comment: U have point there, but I'm stuck with creating animation for my project for a while now, I looked many diferrent tutorials and dont know how to make it work. I have to say i dont want to anyone to tell me what to do next. I just need some small tip. Looking at this code I dont see why it is not working.

Comment: Don't try to start big. Animation is hard. Start small... see if you can create a canvas element and just draw a box. Next, fill the box with a single, static image. That'll get you most of the way there. Downloading a completed project and trying to read the code is one of the hardest ways to learn.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I'm doing what u said, i know how to create single canvas and draw it in game-screen. Next step i though is was to create animation, and after this i was thinking to create structure that will help me load different animations. I'm trying to write game step by step, I think that way I'll learn more. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to answer your question directly because there simply isn't enough working code in your question to easily diagnose the problem.

Based on your description, most likely you aren't clipping the sprite sheet well enough. You need to provide the x/y/w/h coordinates of the piece of the sprite sheet your want to use. It sounds like you aren't doing that.

Here's a very simply working example of animating a sprite on an HTML5 canvas. Note that this will not work in < IE10.

```js
$(function(){
  
  var spritesheet = new Image(),
      canvas = $("#game")[0].getContext('2d'),
      spriteWidth = 64,
      spriteHeight = 64,
      indexX = 0,
      indexX_max = 7,
      indexY = 11,
      lastFrameUpdate = 0,
      frameRate = 1000 / 16, // 16 frames per second (calculated in milliseconds)
      destX = 0,
      destY = 0;
  
  spritesheet.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Dt6.png';
  
  function drawNextSprite(){
    var currentTime = Date.now(),
        timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastFrameUpdate,
        spriteX,
        spriteY;
    
    // If it's been less than 1/16 of a second since the last update, then
    // don't update the sprite yet
    if ( timeSinceLastUpdate < frameRate ){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(drawNextSprite);
      return;
    }
    
    lastFrameUpdate = currentTime;
    
    if ( indexX > indexX_max ) indexX = 0;
    if ( destX > 80 ) destX = -spriteWidth;
    
    // find the next sprite image to use
    spriteX = spriteWidth * indexX;
    spriteY = spriteHeight * indexY;
    
    // clear the area we last drew on (so that we don't leave a trail)
    canvas.clearRect( destX, destY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight );
    canvas.drawImage(
      spritesheet, // the spritesheet
      spriteX, spriteY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, // where is the sprite frame?
      destX, destY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight // where should we draw it on the canvas?
    );
    
    // increment to the next sprite image
    indexX++;
    // move our sprite across the screen
    destX += 3;
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawNextSprite);
  }
  
  drawNextSprite(); // draw the first frame
  
  
});
```

```css
#game{
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="game" height="80" width="80"></canvas>
```

<sub>Information about the sprite sheet I used, including associated copyrights, can be found here: http://opengameart.org/content/universal-lpc-sprite-male-01</sub>
<sub>Copyright/Attribution Notice: Gaurav Munjal</sub>